# REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING when saving data

Tags: apex, aura, contact, upsert, push

Hello I'm getting this error when saving data from a form to database. This field isn't a field from My contact I just add it to try to solve the issues, but nothing happens.
11:32:59:059 FATAL_ERROR System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Faltan campos obligatorios: [Apellidos]: [Apellidos]

I'm adding my code here, I'm just starting with Salesforce(4 days) and I'm following some trail challenges:

contactosApp.app

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
        <!-- This component is the real "app" -->
        <c:contactos/>
</aura:application>
```

contactos.cmp:

```
<aura:component controller="contactosBusquedaController">
    <aura:attribute name="contactoVacio" type="Contact"
                    default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact',
                        'Name': '',
                        'Apellidos':'',
                        'Height__c': 0,
                        'Gender__c': '',
                        'HairColor__c': '',
                        'EyesColor__c': '',
                        'DNI__c':0}"/>
        
    <aura:attribute name="searchedContact" type="Contact"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="mensaje" type="String"/> 
    <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
    <!-- Nombre, Altura, Género, Color de cabello, Color de ojos, numero de documento -->
    <lightning:layout class="slds-page-header slds-page-header_object-home">
        <lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:icon iconName="standard:scan_card" alternativeText="Mis Contactos"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">
            <div class="page-section page-header">
                <h1 class="slds-text-heading_label">Contactos</h1>
                <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium">Mis Contactos</h2>
            </div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
    <!-- / PAGE HEADER -->
    <!-- NEW CONTACT FORM -->
    <lightning:layout class="slds-align_absolute-center">
        <lightning:layoutItem  padding="around-small" size="6">
            <!-- CREATE NEW CONTACT -->
    <div aria-labelledby="buscarcontactform">
        <fieldset class="slds-box slds-theme_default slds-container_small">
            <lightning:input aura:id="busquedaform" 
                             name="DNI"
                             placeholder="Escriba un DNI a buscar...."/>
            <lightning:button label="Buscar"
                              class="slds-m-top_medium"
                              variant="brand"
                              onclick="{!c.clickBuscar}"/>
            <p>{!v.mensaje}</p>
         </fieldset>
     </div>
        
    <div aria-labelledby="newcontactform">
        <!-- BOXED AREA -->
        <fieldset class="slds-box slds-theme_default slds-container_small">
        <legend id="newcontactform" class="slds-text-heading_small
          slds-p-vertical_medium">
          Contacto
        </legend>
        <!-- CREATE NEW CONTACT FORM -->
        <form class="slds-form_stacked">
            <lightning:input aura:id="contactform"
                             name="contactname"
                             value="{!v.contactoVacio.Name}"
                             required="true"
                             label=""
                             placeholder="Ingrese Nombre del Contacto...."/>
            <lightning:input aura:id="contactform"
                             name="contactapellido"
                             value="{!v.contactoVacio.Apellidos}"
                             required="true"
                             label=""
                             placeholder="Ingrese Apellido del Contacto...."/>
            <lightning:input type="number" aura:id="contactform"
                             name="contactheight"
                             min="0.1"
                             formatter=""
                             step="0.01"
                             value="{!v.contactoVacio.Height__c}"
                             label="Estatura"
                             placeholder="Ingrese Estatura"
                             messageWhenRangeUnderflow="Enter a height that's at least 0.1"/>
            <lightning:select aura:id="contactform" 
                              name="contactgender" 
                              required="true"
                              label=""
                              value = "{!v.contactoVacio.Gender__c}">
                            <option value="">Seleccione Genero...</option>
                            <option value="Masculino">masculino</option>
                            <option value="Femenino">femenino</option>
                            <option value="No Binario">no binario</option>
            </lightning:select>
            <lightning:input aura:id="contactform" 
                             name="contacthaircolor"
                             value="{!v.contactoVacio.HairColor__c}"
                             label=""
                             placeholder="Ingrese Color de Cabello...."/>
            <lightning:input aura:id="contactform" 
                             name="contacteyescolor"
                             value="{!v.contactoVacio.EyesColor__c}"
                             label=""
                             placeholder="Ingrese Color de Ojos...."/>
            <lightning:input type="number" aura:id="contactform"
                             name="contactDNI"
                             value="{!v.contactoVacio.DNI__c}"
                             label="DNI"
                             placeholder="Ingrese DNI...."/>
            
            <lightning:button label="Save Changes"
                              class="slds-m-top_medium"
                              variant="brand"
                              onclick="{!c.clickCreate}"/>
        </form>
        <!-- / CREATE NEW CONTACT FORM -->
      </fieldset>
      <!-- / BOXED AREA -->
    </div>
    <!-- / CREATE NEW CONTACT -->
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
    <!-- / NEW EXPENSE FORM -->
</aura:component>
```

contactosController.js

```
({
    clickCreate: function(component, event, helper) {
        let validContacto = component.find('contactform').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
            // Displays error messages for invalid fields
            inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
            return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
        }, true);
        // If we pass error checking, do some real work
        if(validContacto){
            // Create the new expense
            let newContacto = component.get("v.contactoVacio");
            console.log("Create contacto: " + JSON.stringify(newContacto));
            helper.createContacto(component, newContacto);
        }
    },
    
   
    clickBuscar: function(component, event, helper) {
        // Create the action
        let dni = parseInt(component.find("busquedaform").get("v.value"));
        console.log(dni)
        let action = component.get("c.getContacts");
        action.setParams({"dni": dni});
        // Add callback behavior for when response is received
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            let state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.contactoVacio", response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else {
                component.set("v.mensaje", "No se encontro ningun contacto con ese DNI");
                console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
            }
        });
        // Send action off to be executed
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

contactosHelper.js

```
({createContacto: function(component, contacto) {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(contacto));
        let action = component.get("c.guardarContacto");
        action.setParams({
            "contacto": contacto
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            let state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                let contactos = component.get("v.contactoVacio");
                expenses.push(response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.contactoVacio", contactos);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

contactosBusquedaController.apcx

```
public with sharing class contactosBusquedaController{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Contact getContacts(Decimal dni) {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Height__c, Gender__c, HairColor__c,
                       EyesColor__c, DNI__c
                FROM Contact WHERE DNI__c = :dni];
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Contact guardarContacto(Contact contacto) {
        // Perform isUpdateable() checking first, then
        upsert contacto;
        return contacto;
    }
}
```

Comment: In Salesforce the LastName of a Contact is a required value. You can't save a Contact without one. Is "Apellidos" the LastName of the Contact in Spanish?
The form should not ask the user to provide Name and LastName. The Name of a Contact is combined from First and LastName (and more). The form should ask for FirstName and LastName.

Comment: That's it! I didn't understand that the first time I read about it. Now is clear.